# What is the difference in Python defaultdict for d.get(key) vs d[key]?

Tags: python, dictionary, defaultdict

I was using python defaultdict and I noticed this:

```
from collections import defautdict

class TrieNode(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.children = defaultdict(TrieNode)
        self.is_word = False

temp = TrieNode()
```

if I do:

```
temp = temp.children['A']
```

`temp` will be a new `TrieNode` instance

but if I do:

```
   temp = temp.children.get('B')
```

`temp` can be None.

Why would `d.get(key)` vs `d[key]` behave differently in defaultdict??

Comment: Because that's what `get` is supposed to do, get a value, if it isn't in the dict, return a default (which defaults to `None`). For a defaultdict, the only thing that changes is that if `__getitem__` recieves a key that isn't in the dict, it *returns a default value from the default factory after setting it for that missing key*. IOW, `.get` and `__getitem__` work differently in regular `dict` objects, so why shouldn't they work differently in `defaultdict` objects?

Comment: I don't think that's a suitable duplicate. It's about the purpose of the `get` method with regular dictionaries. The question here is: What is the point of a `defaultdict` having a `get` method, when *seemingly* `defaultdict[key]` does the same thing as `dict.get(key)`.

Comment: I'm also not sure that's an appropriate duplicate. I think the OP understands the behaviour of `get` vs `__getitem__` for a regular dictionary. The question was why a `defaultdict`'s `get` method doesn't also use the default factory to create a new value. And I think the answer to that is 'because sometimes you don't want to create a new entry'.